# React nesting react based components

Tags: html, reactjs

Is it possible (and how:-)) nesting react based components and modify the nested elements parameters?

```
<ul data-component="nested-sortable" data-item={}>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 1</li>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 2</li>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 3</li>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 4</li>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 5</li>
    <li data-component="nested-item">item 6</li>
</ul>
```

All component is generated based on the above html structure.

**Sorting the elements:**

```
   const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-component="nested-sortable"]');

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        const node = nodes[i];

        let props = {};

        render(
            <NestedSortable {...props}>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: node.innerHTML}}/>
            </NestedSortable>,
            node
        );
    }
```

**Sortable elements:**

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-component="nested-item"]');

for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    const node = nodes[i];
    let props = {};

    render(
        <NestedItem {...props}>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: node.innerHTML}}/>
        </NestedItem>,
        node
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear you can use `React.cloneElement` to components with modified params.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Comment: The problem is that the elements will come from Laravel blade and those can have components. I am really thinking to change to vue :-( react is amassing if all of the elements are react. But I have to support our designers as well and they working on blade files only